# Does analytical solution exist for this convex euclidean affine projection problem with non-negativity constraints?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I've come across this convex optimization problem in my research where I need to project a matrix $X_0$ onto a non-negative affine space constraint and box constraints. Concretely,

$X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, ~ A \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times m}, C > 0, ~ m > q >> n > 1$.

$\displaystyle \min_X || X - X_0 ||_F$, subject to. $~ A X \geq \mathbf{0}_{q\times n}, ~0 \leq X_{ij} \leq C ~~~\forall i,j$.

Here, C is a constant. What would be the most efficient way to solve this problem? First, does analytical solution already exist? Boyd's book section 8.1.1 discusses similar problems but it's restricted to half spaces, box constraints, and cones. Is this problem reducible to a known problem with analytical solution?

[Edit per @copper.hat] Yes the matrix has a special structure. I've writing the original formulation to describe the structure of the matrix $A$. So the matrix has only 1, 0, or -1 with some structure which could be utilized.

$\displaystyle \min_{B,Z} || B - B_0 ||_F + ||Z - Z_0||_F$, subject to. $B_{i,j} > Z^{i}_{k,j} ~~\forall k=1,\cdots,p, ~B_{i,j} \leq C, ~Z^{i}_{k,j}\geq 0$

$B \in \mathbb{R}^{v\times n}, ~Z^{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}, ~Z = [Z^{1}; \cdots; Z^{v}] \in \mathbb{R}^{v p \times n}$.

Does this parameterization make the problem more solvable? Would this original formulation have an analytic solution?

Comment: Unless $A$ has some restrictions, I doubt that an analytic solution exists, but the above can be formulated as a quadratic program. In fact, it is a nearest point computation to a compact, convex set. On simple (slow) approach would be the Frank–Wolfe algorithm.

Comment: It transforms to a second-order cone program. Plenty of solvers can handle SOCPs, but copper.hat is correct, there is no analytical solution.

Comment: @copper.hat, I've edited the question and wrote out the original formulation which reveal the special structure in the A matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no analytical solution to this problem for general $m$, $n$, $q$, $A$, $C$.

It is, however, easily converted to a form that is readily solved numerically. A potential  conceptual block is that the objective and constraints involve functions on matrices, but it is not difficult to see around those using [Kronecker products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \|\mathop{\textrm{vec}}(X-X_0)\|_2 \\
\text{subject to} & (I\otimes A) \mathop{\textrm{vec}}(X) \geq 0 \\
                  & 0 \leq \mathop{\textrm{vec}}(X) \leq \mathop{\textrm{vec}}(C)
\end{array}$$
Henceforth, let's use an bar as shorthand for $\mathop{\textrm{vec}}$, and define $\tilde{A}\triangleq (I\otimes A)$, so that
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \|\bar{X}-\bar{X}_0\|_2 \\
\text{subject to} & \tilde{A} \bar{X} \geq 0 \\
                  & 0 \leq \bar{X} \leq \bar{C}
\end{array}$$
From here we then have a couple of options. One is to square the objective, which will not change the optimal point:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \|\bar{X}-\bar{X}_0\|_2^2 = \bar{X}^T \bar{X} - (2\bar{X_0})^T \bar{X} + \bar{X}_0^T\bar{X}_0 \\
\text{subject to} & \tilde{A} \bar{X} \geq 0 \\
                  & 0 \leq \bar{X} \leq \bar{C}
\end{array}$$
This is a simple convex [quadratic program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming). There are a variety of tools available to solve this problem.

Alternatively, we can linearize the objective:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & y \\
\text{subject to} & \| \bar{X} - \bar{X}_0 \|_2 \leq y \\
                  & \tilde{A} \bar{X} \geq 0 \\
                  & 0 \leq \bar{X} \leq \bar{C}
\end{array}$$
Now this is in the form of a [second-order cone program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming). Again, there are a variety of solvers available for problems of such type.

To be fair, it can be tedious and error-prone to convert this problem to the very specific standard forms solvers expect. That is where a modeling framework can help. For instance, my MATLAB-based framework [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx) can express this problem naturally:

```
cvx_begin
    variable X(m,n)
    minimize( norm(X-X0,'Fro') )
    A * X >= 0
    0 <= X <= C
cvx_end
```

No need to mess with Kronecker products at all.

Comment: I've edited my question which reveals the structure of the matrix A. Would you think that it simplifies and renders an analytical solution?

Comment: I doubt it. There's nothing to fear from a computational solution.